# Can $CO_2$ be separated into $C$ and $ O_2$?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biophysics, molecules

I'm doing a little bit of research for an experiment that I want to conduct in science and it relies on that one question. So,

- Is it possible to separate a $CO_2$ molecule into a $C$ and $O_2$?

  - Has this been done before, and what were the results? Is this even feasible?
  - How much energy is required to split the $CO_2$ molecule into a $C$ and $O_2$?

Comment: Photosynthesis in plant followed by compression and heating. See how anthracine coal is formed.

Comment: Post this is chemistry stack exchange

Comment: @ShankRam: scientifically this problem has aspects that strongly belong in physics: the bonds that keep molecules together are a Quantum Mechanical phenomenon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows insufficient research efforts.

Comment: This is a highly relevant question and a hot research topic. Creating such an experiment in lab *efficiently* (Artificial photosynthesis) have high potential in constructing energy efficient solar cells. For e.g. have a look at [this](http://solarfuelshub.org/). I strongly oppose to voting this down as the search for an answer could prove to be a milestone.

Comment: It's definitely chemistry; it's not asking for any physical insight.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Definitely not. This comes under Biophysics. Dumping such a question in a broad area like Chemistry is rather unwise. Could you explain why the question is *definitely chemistry*?

Comment: @sathyam: where is the actual physics in the question? And the bio bit? It could be biophysics, if he mentioned specifically how the decomposition occurred in photosynthesis; but he hasn't - and should we fill that in for him? It could come under inorganic chemistry given it's one of the smallest possible molecule that involves carbon - it's hardly organic chemistry; he's simply asking whether it's *possible*.

Comment: In Gerts answer, the term *Enthalpy of Formation* is used - this is specifically a chemistry term ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah *he's simply asking whether...* Please don't make such blind assumptions and see the problem objectively. $E_{dissociation}$ is the central concern. $2nd$ question, the thermodynamic feasibility of the reaction. Which reaction? There may be many. The $1st$ and $2nd$ questions are central to the thermodynamics of a chemical reaction. To make things more interesting this is one of the most sought after by biophysicists as well as Photochemists. Does it comes under Physical chemistry? *yes*. What about biochemical relevance? *High.* And do *thermodynamics* have anything to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32969/discussion-between-sathyam-and-mozibur-ullah).

Comment: @sure: I tried to go into chat - but no go; all that is of relevance, and in a chemistry like way; but *none* of that is in the question; the question can be generically asked of any reaction; I do by the way think that the intersection between disciplines are important ie biochemistry, biophysics or the physics of chemistry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By heating *any* substance to a sufficiently high temperature it will decompose into its constituent atoms because chemical bonds do not survive the inter-atomic movements between the nuclei, at these temperatures.

That part of quantum physics we usually call Chemistry thus has a fairly limited temperature window: very broadly speaking (because it depends strongly on the type of molecule) above $5000\:\mathrm{K}$ all molecular structure (chemical bonding) has been lost and substances become 'atom soup'. That's why in very hot bodies (like stars) no chemical structures exist.

Regards the energy needed to decompose $\mathrm{CO_2}$, simply look up the Enthalpy of Formation of that substance and invert the sign. In reality, thermal decomposition will need more Enthalpy because of heat losses at such high temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it possible to separate a CO<sub>2</sub> molecule into a C and O<sub>2</sub>?

A:Yes, one can split any molecule down to its constituents. In other words, there is no chemical compound on earth that cannot be split into constituent atoms.

Q: How much energy is required to split the CO<sub>2</sub> molecule into a C and O<sub>2</sub>?

This slightly depends on what kind of carbon you are talking about. Please check the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_carbon) for different allotropes of carbon.
 
A back-of-an-envelope type of calculation:
- to break one C=O bond in CO<sub>2</sub> molecule requires 800 kJ/mol
- to form a O=O bond in O<sub>2</sub> molecule releases 495 kJ/mol
- the cohesive energy of diamond is roughly 7.9 eV/atom (762 kJ/mol)

1600-495-762=343 kJ/mol